# refer to appendix in `apxproof`

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices, cleveref

I am using [apxproof](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/apxproof/apxproof.pdf) and would like to reference the repeated/generated appendix. I tried adding the following line to my preamble:

```
\usepackage[bibliography=common]{apxproof}
\renewcommand{\appendixprelim}{\clearpage\onecolumn\appendix\appendixpage\section{}\label{apx:delayed_proofs}}
```

and then referring to the appendix via `\cref{apx:delayed_proofs}` but `\cref` does not give me text in the hyperlink that reads "Appendix A".

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,DIV=10]{scrartcl}

%
%%
%%% preamble
%%
%

%%% main packages
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482222/automatically-use-german-style-french-quotes
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\appendixpagename}{\sffamily}{}{}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,bm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%%% appendix proofs
\usepackage[bibliography=common]{apxproof}
\renewcommand{\appendixprelim}{\clearpage\onecolumn\appendix\appendixpage\section{}\label{apx:delayed_proofs}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheoremrep{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\begin{lemmarep}[Test]
  Test!
\end{lemmarep}
\begin{proof}
  Test!
\end{proof}
Here's a reference to the \cref{apx:delayed_proofs}!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually execute `\appendixprelim`, and there's no `\section` directive either. What is `\label{apx:delayed_proofs}` supposed to latch on to?

Comment: Ah thanks! let me edit it. I encountered a new issue when adding `\section{}` to the `\renewcommand` in that it duplicates appendix "A". I'd like to be able to refer to the apx-proof appendix without introducing new appendices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\appendixpagename}{\sffamily}{}{}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage[bibliography=common]{apxproof}
\renewcommand{\appendixprelim}{\clearpage\onecolumn\appendix\appendixpage}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheoremrep{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\begin{lemmarep}[Test]
  Test!
\end{lemmarep}
\begin{toappendix}
  \label{apx:delayed_proofs}
\end{toappendix}
\begin{proof}
  Test!
\end{proof}
Here's a reference to the \cref{apx:delayed_proofs}!
\end{document}
```